# Marking modified cell/row $dirty in ui-grid 3.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a plunker that is ALMOST just like it is supposed to be. I have to add one requirement to it and I can't find it in the docs or on google.

The grid is set (to be like Excel) where you can begin to edit and the tab key will move from row to row. I need SOME WAY to mark a cell as $dirty if a change was made.

The requirement is an update button to save the ENTIRE grid if there were any changes (again, he wants it just like Excel).

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5xtKPvrqayuk3uHE9u6?p=preview).

The issue: double-click an editable cell (name, status, M, T, W, H, F) and the tab key will cycle through the entire grid. If a cell value is changed, I need a way to mark it as dirty!

CODE:
(index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="lodash.js@*" data-semver="3.10.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <strong>Data Length:</strong>
 {{ gridOptions.data.length | number }}
        <br />
      <strong>Last Cell Edited:</strong>
 {{msg.lastCellEdited}}
        <br />
      <div ui-grid="gridOpts" ui-grid-edit="" ui-grid-cellnav="" class="grid"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

(app.js)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit', 'ui.grid.cellNav']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.$scope = $scope;
  $scope.pending_view = true;
  $scope.gridOpts = {
    enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
    enableGridMenu: true
  };

   var dataset = [{
    vote_pending: false,
    has_comment: false,
    is_stale: false,
    is_watched: false,
    disbursement_issue: false,
    name: "Jon",
    status: 1,
    M: 9,
    T: 9,
    W: 9,
    H: 9,
    F: 4
  }, {
    vote_pending: true,
    has_comment: true,
    is_stale: true,
    is_watched: true,
    disbursement_issue: true,
    name: "Robbie",
    status: 1,
    M: 8,
    T: 8,
    W: 8,
    H: 8,
    F: 8
  }, {
    vote_pending: false,
    has_comment: false,
    is_stale: true,
    is_watched: true,
    disbursement_issue: false,
    name: "Brad",
    status: 1,
    M: 8,
    T: 8,
    W: 8,
    H: 8,
    F: 8
  }, {
    vote_pending: false,
    has_comment: true,
    is_stale: false,
    is_watched: false,
    disbursement_issue: false,
    name: "Paul",
    status: 1,
    M: 8,
    T: 8,
    W: 8,
    H: 8,
    F: 8
  }, {
    vote_pending: false,
    has_comment: true,
    is_stale: false,
    is_watched: true,
    disbursement_issue: false,
    name: "Billie",
    status: 2,
    M: 8,
    T: 4,
    W: 4,
    H: 4,
    F: 0
  }];

  $scope.getTotal=function(a, b, c, d, e) {
    return a+b+c+d+e;
  };

  $scope.gridweek = true;

  var sByName = _.sortBy(dataset, 'name');
  var sPending = _.sortByAll(dataset, ['is_watched', 'vote_pending', 'has_comment', 'disbursement_issue', 'is_stale']).reverse();

  $scope.gridOpts.data = sPending;

  $scope.pendingSort = function() {
    if($scope.gridOpts.data === sByName) {
      $scope.gridOpts.data = sPending;
    } else if($scope.gridOpts.data === sPending) {
      $scope.gridOpts.data = sByName;
    }
  };

  $scope.gridOpts.columnDefs = [
    {
      name: 'id',
      enableCellEdit: false,
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      headerCellTemplate: 'pending.hdr.html',
      cellTemplate: 'pending.icons.html',
      width: '15%'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'name',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'Name',
      cellClass: 'text-left cBlue',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center bGreen',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      width: '12%'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'status',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'Status',
      editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      cellClass: 'text-left cBlue',
      cellFilter: 'mapStatus',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center bGreen',
      editDropdownValueLabel: 'status',
      editDropdownOptionsArray: [
        {
          id: 1,
          status: 'FT'
        }, 
        {
          id: 2,
          status: 'PT'
        }
      ],
      visible: $scope.gridweek,
      width: '14%'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'M',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'M',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      type: 'number',
      cellFilter: 'number:1',
      cellClass: 'text-right cBlue',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center bGreen',
      width: '8%'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'T',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'T',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      type: 'number',
      cellFilter: 'number:1',
      cellClass: 'text-right cBlue',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center bGreen',
      width: '8%'
    }, 
    {
      name: 'W',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'W',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      type: 'number',
      cellFilter: 'number:1',
      cellClass: 'text-right cBlue',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center bGreen',
      width: '8%'
    },
    {
      name: 'H',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'H',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      type: 'number',
      cellFilter: 'number:1',
      cellClass: 'text-right cBlue',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center bGreen',
      width: '8%'
    },
    {
      name: 'F',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'F',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      type: 'number',
      cellFilter: 'number:1',
      cellClass: 'text-right cBlue',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center bGreen',
      width: '8%'
    },
    {
      field: 'total',
      enableCellEdit: false,
      displayName: 'Total',
      enableColumnMenu: false,
      type: 'number',
      cellFilter: 'number:1',
      cellClass: 'text-right',
      headerCellClass: 'text-center bGreen',
      cellTemplate: 'total.tmpl.html',
      width: '10%'
    }
  ];

  $scope.msg = {};

  $scope.gridOpts.onRegisterApi = function(gridApi) {
    //set gridApi on scope
    $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
      $scope.msg.lastCellEdited = 'edited row id:' + rowEntity.id + ' Column:' + colDef.name + ' newValue:' + newValue + ' oldValue:' + oldValue;
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  };
}])

.filter('mapStatus', function() {
  var statusHash = {
    1: 'Full Time',
    2: 'Part Time'
  };

  return function(input) {
    if (!input) {
      return '';
    } else {
      return statusHash[input];
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: You already using `gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit` which you can get the new and old value. So what's the problem?

Comment: I just can't figure out how to "mark" the cell OR the row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to adding a thin layer on top of the dataset to track record dirty status.

```
var records = [];
angular.forEach(dataset, function (rawdata) {
    var record = {};
    //Track changed attrs, 
    //keys are the changed properties and 
    //values are an array of values [origValue, newValue].
    record.changedAttrs = {};

    //record dirty status
    Object.defineProperty(record, 'isDirty', {
        get: function () {
            return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(record.changedAttrs).length > 0; 
        }
    }); 

    angular.forEach(rawdata, function (value, key) {
        Object.defineProperty(record, key, {
            get: function () {
                return rawdata[key];  
            },

            set: function (value) {
                var origValue = record.changedAttrs[key] ? 
                    record.changedAttrs[key][0] : rawdata[key];

                if(value !== origValue) {
                    record.changedAttrs[key] = [origValue, value];
                } else {
                    delete record.changedAttrs[key];  
                }
                rawdata[key] = value;
            }
        })      
    });
    records.push(record);  
});
```

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/veRPCm6v354fKUG0M1Q5?p=preview). Providing a custom row template and an extra line of css, the row bg color will change to yellow when the row is dirty.

```
rowTemplate: '<div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.uid" ' + 
'ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid="rowRenderIndex + \'-\' + col.uid + \'-cell\'" ' + 
'class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader , \'row-dirty\': row.entity.isDirty}" ' + 
'role="{{col.isRowHeader ? \'rowheader\' : \'gridcell\'}}" ui-grid-cell></div>'
```

css

```
.ui-grid-cell.row-dirty {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: I will definitely mark this as the correct answer but I had once follow-up question: Instead of adding a column to the grid, is there a ui-grid way to add a background-color of light yellow to the whole row if that record has been modified?

Comment: You can use a custom rowTemplate to change the row color based on `isDirty` property, see the updated answer and plunker.

Answer (score 4):

I create a dirty flag on scope:

```
$scope.dirty = false;
```

and I update the function what monitors editions:

```
gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit($scope, function(rowEntity, colDef, newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.$apply(function(scope) {
    scope.dirty = true;
  });
});
```

please see on plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bSTXqp7wzLDL74rN3PII?p=preview

Comment: This is a clean and concise solution. However, I need the cell of at least the row of the change indicated.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to merlins answer.
His css style didn't work for me. What I did is:

```
.ui-grid-row-dirty div {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

which will set every cells (within the row) bg color to yellow.